# iOS application continuous integration with Travis CI

Tags: ios, swift, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I tried to integrate Travis CI into my iOS application.

[image]

I get an error stating:

```
The command "xctool -project RomanToBase10.xcodeproj -scheme RomanToBase10 build test" exited with 4.
```

My `.travis.yml` looks like this:

```
language: swift  
osx_image: xcode8.3
xcode_project: RomanToBase10.xcodeproj
xcode_scheme: RomanToBase10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your are using Xcode 8.3. Travis CI uses Facebooks xctool which does not fully support Xcode 8.

For more details see this issues for Travis: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6430

Answer (score 0):

You can refer link https://medium.com/@ahire.pawan/continuous-deployment-and-continuous-integration-for-ios-using-travis-ci-and-github-f7e604018096
for CI/CD for iOS using Travis CI and GitHub